# How To Outline a PNG (Transparent) image with CSS?

Tags: css

Title says most of it. I need to make a transparent image outlined or make it glow when hovered, i tried doing it for the whole day but not sucess yet. Any suggestions/help?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the code you have tried?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Image Swap on Hover...

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/bqujwvtv/1/)**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="main" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food/1/" />
  <img class="hover" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food/2/" />
</div>


img.hover {
  display: none;
}
.wrapper:hover img.main {
  display: none;
}
.wrapper:hover img.hover {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this creates a box over the PNG image, it doesn't outline the curves of the image.

Comment: the curves of what image?  you haven't provided any code or images.  if you want rounded corners on the rectangle, simply use the `border-radius` property. `border-radius: 5px;`

Comment: http://10bestones.com/1233-2

Here is the link to the page, scroll down to the last printer image and hover over it, you will see what i mean :)

Comment: ok well your image there is still square, it just has a transparent background.  You will have to create an identical image with the outline you want (using photoshop or something) then swap the images on hover.  I will update the answer to show you the hover code

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for

Comment: I actually found a great page with a TON of CSS codes:
http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/

THanks a lot for trying to help though, i really appreciate it.

Comment: Yep, just saw what you posted, thanks a lot, that was what i was looking for!